# Как задать класс последнему элементу в списке при определенном условии?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть список:

```
<ul>
    <li>Текст</li>
    <li>Текст</li>
    <li>Текст</li>
    <li>Текст</li>
    <li>Текст</li>
</ul>
```

При клике на разные кнопки все элементы списка скрываются, и некоторые показываются:

```
<ul>
    <li style="display: block;">Текст</li>
    <li style="display: none;">Текст</li>
    <li style="display: block;">Текст</li>
    <li style="display: none;">Текст</li>
    <li style="display: none;">Текст</li>
</ul>
```

Как задать класс последнему тэгу `li`, имеющему свойство `display: block` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте

```
$("li:visible:last").addClass("class_name")
```

Answer (score 1):

Если через чистый js

```
<ul id='list'>
    <li style="display: block;">Текст</li>
    <li style="display: none;">Текст</li>
    <li style="display: block;">Текст</li>
    <li style="display: none;">Текст</li>
    <li style="display: none;">Текст</li>
</ul>

var liArray = document.getElementById('list').getElementsByTagName("li"),
        cur = null;

for(var cur, i = 0, count = liArray.length-1; i < count; i++) {
    if(liArray[i].style.display == 'block') {
    cur = liArray[i];
  }
}

if(cur) {
    cur.className += " my-class";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p23ob95y/1/